# facebook connect for android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Using facebook connect from [phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/), It is working properly in emulator but while in android devices, it is not working it giving message.

```
 function login() {
            FB.login(
                     function(response) {
                     if (response.authResponse) {
                      me();
                     } else {
                     alert('not logged in');
                     }
                     },
                     { perms: "user_birthday,friends_birthday,email" }
                     );
        }
```

**Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login! Facebook error:android_key_not_configured:the android key hash for this application is not configured.**

Please suggest what to do for connection?